# Github vs Azure DevOps Version Control

Tags: github, azure-devops

Is it better to host code on Github or in the DevOps code platform?

We have some specific repositories hosted on an enterprise Github. Others in the DevOps version control within a DevOps project. A question came up about a new repo and I am wondering pros and cons of putting it in one vs the other? I personally prefer the Github interface but wondering if we will hit some limitations with pipelines if we put it in there.

Did I also read somewhere that Microsoft is ultimately planning to decommission DevOps version control and so that would be a factor in the long term? (I couldn't find a Microsoft article about this)

Comment: Questions that ask things like "Is it better to...?" are opinion-based and thus are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing immediately planned (3-4 years) around ADO retirement. This is emphasize by the recognition there are more mature tools in Azure DevOps around Project Management and event some features which have no immediate counterparts in GitHub. Azure Test Plans is the prime example if you are using manual test cases there is no planned alternative on [GitHub's roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/github/projects/4247).

The focus has been on integration between GitHub and Azure DevOps. There have been recent announcements that support this. Items such as [Advance Security for GitHub coming to ADO](https://partner.github.com/2022/10/12/azure-devops-article.html) and the ability to connect [GitHub to Azure DevOps Orgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cross-service/github-integration?view=azure-devops). [ADO Public roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)

I am seeing more and more where organizations host their source code in GitHub to take advantage of newer features such as [codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces) and the recent announcement of [Co-Pilot X](https://github.com/features/preview/copilot-x).

Then Azure DevOps can read the GitHub repository and then the organization can decide if they want to use ADO Pipelines or GitHub Actions. Both are supported. The [tasks, project management, and test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/link-to-from-github?view=azure-devops) would still live in Azure DevOps.

The reoccurring message I am hearing is if you are a startup or brand new should evaluate GitHub first; however, Azure DevOps is a valid option as most major organizations, including Microsoft, are still heavily invested in the product. Thus there is a focus on integration between the two products and it's more of an AND then a VS conversation.

Comment: Thankyou this is a perfect answer and very helpful. Wish this had not been down rated by editors.